# Conditional CSS by PHP

Tags: php, html, css

Could anybody tell me what I am going wrong?

I am trying to change CSS style asking with PHP.

```
 <?php
    include 'connect.php';
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Lista de mensajes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid mb-10">


        <table class="table table-striped fs-2">
            <thead class="text-uppercase">
                <tr>
                <th scope="col"  class="col-sm-2">fecha</th>
                <th scope="col">mensaje</th>
                <th scope="col" class="col-sm-1">prioridad</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

                <?php

                    $sql="SELECT * FROM mensajes WHERE 1 ORDER BY prioridad DESC,fecha DESC";

                    $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$sql);


                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                        $id=$row['id'];
                        $hotel=$row['hotel'];
                        $mensaje=$row['mensaje'];
                        $fecha=new datetime($row['fecha']);
                        $fecha=$fecha->format('d-m-y H:i:s');
                        $prioridad=$row['prioridad'];
                        if($prioridad==true){
                            echo '<tr class="text-danger">';
                        }else{
                            echo '<tr>';
                        }
                        
                        echo '<td scope="row">'.$fecha.'</td>
                        <td>'.$hotel." - ".$mensaje.'</td>
                        <td>'.$prioridad.'</td>
                        </tr>';
                    }

                ?>

                
                   
            </tbody>
        </table>
        

        <?php
            if(!mysqli_close($con)){
                die(mysqli_error());
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML output seems to be correct but I can only see the last entry in red

```
 <table class="table table-striped fs-2">
        <thead class="text-uppercase">
            <tr>
            <th scope="col"  class="col-sm-2">fecha</th>
            <th scope="col">mensaje</th>
            <th scope="col" class="col-sm-1">prioridad</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr class="text-danger"><td scope="row">23-10-22 10:58:54</td>
                    <td>PLB - rojo OOOO?</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    </tr><tr class="text-danger"><td scope="row">23-10-22 08:58:02</td>
                    <td>BPC - BPC y prioridad</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    </tr><tr><td scope="row">24-10-22 08:01:54</td>
                    <td>BPK - TEST</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    </tr><tr><td scope="row">23-10-22 10:26:29</td>
                    <td>BGA - Prueba BGA con prioridad</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    </tr>
            
               
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

connect.php just make a connection to a mysql database with a single table.

I would like to show the text in red when the priority is true or 1

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see any CSS in your question.

Comment: So, how many rows are in the table? How many rows should be red? How many rows are actually being output? Are you saying it doesn't output the right number of rows, or the row with the "text-danger" class doesn't actually show in red, or what? The wording of the question is unclear.

Comment: If you check the HTML output two table rows have the class text-danger from bootstrap but only the last row I insert into database table get the style.

Comment: You didn't put anything about: _"inserting rows into a database table"_, in your question. This might just be sloppy language? Do you mean: _"outputting rows in a HTML table"_?

Comment: The red color of the danger class is overwritten by the `table-striped` class.

Comment: If you use the `class="text-danger"` in the `<td>` in the rows, instead of in the `<tr>`, it will work.

Comment: The reason for this is that `table-striped` changes the styling of a whole row, but if you use `<td class="text-danger">` this overwrites that by changing the styling of the `<td>`.

Comment: See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/abKoRrw

Comment: @AHaworth  It's all there:  https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, don’t use `while` for database fetch. Use instead `if`

Secondly, something like `$avar=areturn()` will always be true, so you should define `$row` separately before the loop.